# String splitting in python by finding non-zero character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to do the following split:

```
input: 0x0000007c9226fc output: 7c9226fc
input: 0x000000007c90e8ab output: 7c90e8ab
input: 0x000000007c9220fc output: 7c9220fc
```

I use the following line of code to do this but it does not work!

```
split = element.rpartition('0')
```

I got these outputs which are wrong!

```
input: 0x000000007c90e8ab output: e8ab
input: 0x000000007c9220fc output: fc
```

what is the fastest way to do this kind of split?
The only idea for me right now is to make a loop and perform checking but it is a little time consuming.

I should mention that the number of zeros in input is not fixed.

Comment: `your_input[10:]` (you'll most likely want to properly parse this, your idea of splitting on separation of non-zero does not seem safe at all)

Comment: Are there always the same number of leading chars?

Comment: Is your input a number (for instance, 0x000000007c9226fc is 2089953020) or a string ('0x000000007c9226fc') ?

Comment: Is your input always going to be a string representation of a hexadecimal number?  Using string manipulation is the wrong tool for that problem.

Comment: the number of zeros is not fixed and my be there are the different number of zeros at first. Also it is a string

Comment: @cyrbil you can tell it's a string simply by the code submitted thus far.

Comment: @Foon yes. So how can I represent it?

Comment: See mhawke's answer for how to parse string representations ('%x' % int(s, 16) will return a string; if you just do str(int(s,16)) it will convert it into the decimal equivalent

Answer (score 5):

Each string can be converted to an integer using `int()` with a base of 16. Then convert back to a string.

```
for s in '0x000000007c9226fc', '0x000000007c90e8ab', '0x000000007c9220fc':
    print '%x' % int(s, 16)
```

Output

```
7c9226fc
7c90e8ab
7c9220fc
```

Comment: What if the 11th character is a '0', which is required by the program. Since the user is printing the last 8 characters of the input.

Comment: The original program should interpret the input as a hex number and then display it in any way it wants. For this reason I consider this answer the only correct one.

Answer (score 4):

```
input[2:].lstrip('0')
```

That should do it. The `[2:]` skips over the leading `0x` (which I assume is always there), then the `lstrip('0')` removes all the zeros from the left side.

In fact, we can use `lstrip` ability to remove more than one leading character to simplify:

```
input.lstrip('x0')
```

Comment: What if the 11th character is a '0', which is required by the program. Since the user is printing the last 8 characters of the input.

Comment: @user3337714 very good point! You need some kind of check for that special case, to replace the result with `'0'`. (I assume you meant all zeros, since trailing zeros aren't affected by `lstrip`).

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, you are right. I did mean all zeros and I understand trailing zeros are not affected by `lstrip`.

Answer (score 1):

[format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) is handy for this:

```
>>> print '{:x}'.format(0x000000007c90e8ab)
7c90e8ab

>>> print '{:x}'.format(0x000000007c9220fc)
7c9220fc
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case you can just do

```
your_input[10:]
```

You'll most likely want to properly parse this; your idea of splitting on separation of non-zero does not seem safe at all.

Seems to be [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

If the number of characters in a string is constant then you can use
the following code.

```
input = "0x000000007c9226fc"
output = input[10:]
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

Also, since you are using `rpartition`which is [defined](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) as

> str.rpartition(sep) 
>   Split the string at the last occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing two empty strings, followed by the string itself.

Since your input can have multiple 0's, and rpartition only splits the last occurrence this a malfunction in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for `0x00000` or its type is `(0x[0]+)` and than replace it with space.

```
import re
st="0x000007c922433434000fc"
reg='(0x[0]+)'
rep=re.sub(reg, '',st)
print rep
```